# pandas: count number of occurrences within one year from date in row, grouped by subject

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe which contains subject ids and dates:

```
    id        date
 0  17  2012-02-16
 1  17  2013-01-26
 2  17  2013-01-27
 3  17  2015-09-13
 4  18  2015-01-28
 5  18  2015-02-12
```

for each row, I would like to know how many entries `row['subject']` has in the year preceding `row['date']`:

```
    id        date count
 0  17  2012-02-16     0
 1  17  2013-01-26     1
 2  17  2013-01-27     2
 3  17  2015-09-13     0
 4  18  2015-01-28     0
 5  18  2015-02-12     1
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where's row['subject']?

Comment: apologies, should be row['id']

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your desired output. I'm not quite sure what is it you want to groupby your data, and what is it you want to count from

Comment: Hi Chris. The desired output is the count column in the second dataframe. E.g. for the row  with id=17 and date=2013-01-27 there are two rows with id=17 and date within the range 2012-01-26 to 2013-01-26 (one year before 2013-01-27). So I suppose the first step is to group by subject, but I don't know where to go from there.